# function returns [object object] instead of string Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

Want to have single function to get the dynamic text value from application.

`getStartDate()` function return as `[object object]` when calling from different function `getDate()` whereas `cy.log(mon...)` from `getStartDate()`  gives the correct date in  the format of string. Also `cy.wrap(mom...)` wrap a correct date in string format

```
   getStartDate(){
         return cy.get('[data-placeholder="Select time range (from)"]').invoke('val').then($da=>{
              cy.log(moment($da,'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss').format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss')+"------------------")  //  returns "03.01.2022 11:10:00"
               return (cy.wrap(moment($da,'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss').format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss').valueOf())) ;Text   // return "03.01.2022 11:10:00"
               
            })
        }
```

Calling function:

```
     getDate(){
        cy.log(this.getStartDate().toString()+"------------") // returns [object object]
        }
```

Kindly let me know how to get the value from `getStartDate()` by calling through out the application

Answer (score 0):

`cy.wrap` is used to create a cypress chainer object. Moreover, you are returning `cy.get(...)` from the function, which is an object. You sould try to use Promises:

```js
async getStartDate() {
         const $da = await cy.get('[data-placeholder="Select time range (from)"]').invoke('val');
         cy.log(moment($da,'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss').format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss')+"------------------")  //  returns "03.01.2022 11:10:00"
         return moment($da,'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss').format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss');
}
```

And use it like this:

```js
getStartDate().then((startDate) => cy.log(startDate));
```

Comment: your solution returns me `Invalid date`

Answer (score 0):

fix code as below :D

```
cy.log(this.getStartDate().toString(),"------------")
```

I hope you find an answer!

Comment: it is not working `cy.log(this.getStartDate().toString(),"------------")` return [object object ]

Comment: Try JSON.stringify(this.getStartDate().toString()) !